# Asynchronous processing in JSP

Tags: jsp

I am working on server side application which uses JSP. Now, the problem is that I have to generate table in HTML which will be computed by a Java function. That Java function takes a lot of time in completing, so I want to show the rest of HTML view and a spinner on place of table. When the function execution is complete, then I want to create the table and update it with rows. I am not sure how to achieve this with JSP. Any ideas on how can we call a Java function asynchronously in JSP and then update the HTML view later? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: So load the table with Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not reinvent the wheel, I suggest you to use a javascript-based implementation such as [JQuery DataTables](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side), so you can easily lazy load your table, delegating the heavy lifting to the server side.

Without such a component, you'll end up having to write yourself the code (not that much really) to load your table using ajax (maybe using prototype.js?) and showing an animated gif of a spinning wheel while the result is not ready. But testing and tuning such a thing against timeouts is IMO worse than using a stable and well tested library such as JQuery DataTables.

Comment: Well the problem is that the data is computed by a Java function. So my primary question is that how do I execute that function asynchronously?

Comment: This depends on how much time it takes. If it takes just a few seconds, lazy loading your table is fine, because the user can wait and this won't be longer than a typical http request timeout. But if your functions takes more than 10 minutes or hours for example, then you have to create a ticket-based system (just like NCBI for example does with gene matching process, you submit the request and get a ticket to get the answer when it's done)